# Ansible & Jinja2 - Place template in directory per variable

Tags: ansible, jinja2

Got a question which is hard to describe, suggestions for improvement to make this question more understandable is appreciated.

Goal: 
First set a variable for a single template, then set a destination based on the variable set. Based on one template. I'd like to avoid using multiple templates for each directory.

Example: `my_jinja.j2`contains:

```
a line of code
/path{{ variable }}/something
another line of code
```

I want to set the template in the directory which is set with `variable`.
If `variable` contains:

```
- /tmp
- /var
```

If `/tmp` is set, the template should be set in `/foo`

If `/var` is set, I want to the template placed in `/bar`

The template for `/tmp` should look like:

```
a line of code
/path/tmp/something
another line of code
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Worth a try:

template:

```
a line of code
/path{{ path_var }}/something
another line of code
```

var:

```
my_list:
  - path: /tmp
    dest: /foo
  - path: /var
    dest: /bar
```

task:

```
- template:
    src: my_jinja.j2
    dest: "/path/to/{{ item.dest }}"
  vars:
    path_var: "{{ item.path }}"
  with_items: "{{ my_list }}"
```